# On which criteia nutch selects TopN docs while crawling?

Tags: nutch

On which criteia nutch selects TopN docs while crawling? And how nutch creates segments.?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things that are taken into account:

1. The score of the url
2. how many urls belonging to the same host are allowed to be crawled.
3. Is the re-fetch time of the url reached ?

Comment: I have two sites to crawl in nutch 2.1 but only one site is getting crawled. How do crawl the second site also along with the first site? I have added both sites to the regex-urlfilter file but only 20 urls got fecthed from the second site while the first site has around 16k urls already fetched and new urls getting fetched are from the first site only.

Comment: @peter Several factors can be there.. is the 2nd site having stringent robots restrictions ? is there any exception while getting the HTTP response/content like ReadTimeOut, Socket etc issues ? are there urls of 2nd host which are eligible for fetching ? could the ones, which are fetched, produce the outlinks ? Running a separate local mode crawl on the 2nd host and checking the logs, segments and crawldb would help to figure out the issue

Comment: the 2nd site has more directories which are disallowed but i dont think it affects the fetching. there are around 180 urls which are unfetched. how do i run a separate local mode crawl? i am using mysql so the segment and crawldb folders are not present.

Comment: @peter: run a separate copy of nutch from NUCH_HOME/runtime/local

Comment: How do i run a separate copy of nutch? i am using mysql to store the data so how can i run a separate copy?

Comment: @peter : i have never tried using nutch with mysql but i might suggest you to try having multiple copies of nutch and run crawl of each SEPARATELY. if that doesnt work out well, please post this as a new question so that others can give their suggestions.

Comment: I am using amazon small instance and the network admin says that it is not possible to install 2 nutch copies on the same small instance. I have tried installing nutch on my windows 7 local machine but i havent been able to install it successfully. Any good easy to install nutch tutorial with mysql on windows 7?

Comment: @peter my experiences are with Linux.. neva had to work on windows. One simple way to get help is to shoot an email to the nutch user group.